# Casting `std::unique_ptr`

Tags: c++, casting, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

Is there any problem in performing dynamic casting via the following function?

```
template<typename Base, typename Derived>
    requires std::is_convertible_v<Derived&, Base&> &&
             std::is_polymorphic_v<Base>
inline std::unique_ptr<Derived> cast_to(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& ptr)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr.release()));
}
```

Comment: If the `dynamic_cast` fails, you leak memory.

Comment: Also from a calling code perspective, the order of the arguments means that you'll always have to specify `cast_to<Base, Derived>` in calling code. If you switch it to `template<typename Derived, typename Base>` you still have to specify `Derived` since there's no way for the compiler to deduce the value of `Derived` from the argument, but you can let template argument deduction figure out what `Base` is. But I wouldn't worry about that until I have a good answer for "What actually is _supposed_ to happen if the downcast fails?"

Comment: @NathanPierson It would answer all my questions if you gave an example of such a dynamic_cast failure. Exactly when my function is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your function can easily leak memory if the cast fails.  Consider the following:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {};
struct Derived2 : Base {};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bp = std::make_unique<Derived1>();

    // bp does not point to a Derived2, so this cast will fail
    auto d2p = cast_to<Base, Derived2>(std::move(bp));
    std::cout << bp.get() << '\n';  // 0
    std::cout << d2p.get() << '\n'; // also 0; object was leaked
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44d4f7a875fdf9b2)

From this snippet you can also see another small issue: because of the order of the template parameters you have to supply them both.  You can't let the compiler deduce `Base` because it comes before `Derived`.

---

With both of those issues in mind, the following would be a better implementation:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base>  // swap the order of template parameters
    requires std::is_convertible_v<Derived&, Base&> &&
             std::is_polymorphic_v<Base>
inline std::unique_ptr<Derived> cast_to(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& ptr)
{
    Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr.get());
    if (d) {
        ptr.release();
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(d);
    }
    return nullptr;  // object is still owned by ptr
}
```

This fixes both of the above issues:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bp = std::make_unique<Derived1>();

    // No need to explicitly specify Base; the compiler can deduce that itself
    auto d2p = cast_to<Derived2>(std::move(bp));
    std::cout << bp.get() << '\n';  // not 0; no leak
    std::cout << d2p.get() << '\n'; // 0
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d984f699b4c1eae)

Comment: I'm so inattentive... Thank you :)